# What type of communication protocol should I use for a shortlived data stream to an web application

Tags: http, websocket, backend, protocols

I am developing a system of backend microservices that constitute an LLM Inference system. Think like openai API. In my microservice that serves as gateway (the front end websites will connect to that), I need to stream a bunch of string for few seconds (20 at max) until the response is finished. I am lost on what kind of protocol or technic or tool etc to use for this. Some details:

**Websockets**

I have used websockets before and now opt not to use them as sticky connections create a problem with downscaling on container orchestration systems. I am aware that I can close the connection one-sided from the server when the transaction stops. However, the problem that I have with that is that I can not send the payload of my request with the connection but immediately after the connection is established. Which is x2 latency and feels bug prone for some reason.

**HTTP Stream**

I am aware that you can directly stream data in normal HTTP endpoints. Problem is browser buffers them so it is not really streaming

**SSE**

Right now I am using short lived sse connections where the initial endpoint is a HTTP post and the responses are on text/event-stream . However browser still buffers them, I don't think it is suppose to. Maybe bug in my code.

So this does not seem like a problem so hard that it requires a novel solution. What would be the standard solution to this following the best practices?